# Geomajas Error"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException"on Feature Info Tool

Tags: java, geomajas

I am using  use geomajas 1.12.0 version.
I have with published road.shp file on map. 
i found this error when i use show feature information tool on my vector layer(road layer) with my road layerOsm layer visible.
I have used geotools  to import the shape file
ERROR o.g.i.s.ConfigurationServiceImpl - Error during getBeanOrNull, not rethrown, Bean named 'layerOsm' must be of type [org.geomajas.layer.VectorLayer], but was actually of type [org.geomajas.layer.osm.OsmLayer]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'layerOsm' must be of type [org.geomajas.layer.VectorLayer], but was actually of type [org.geomajas.layer.osm.OsmLayer]

please see Stack-trace as follows:

15:23:25.019 [914046261@qtp-1772367544-7] ERROR o.g.i.s.ConfigurationServiceImpl - Error during getBeanOrNull, not rethrown, Bean named 'layerOsm' must be of type [org.geomajas.layer.VectorLayer], but was actually of type [org.geomajas.layer.osm.OsmLayer]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'layerOsm' must be of type [org.geomajas.layer.VectorLayer], but was actually of type [org.geomajas.layer.osm.OsmLayer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.geomajas.internal.service.ConfigurationServiceImpl.getBeanOrNull(ConfigurationServiceImpl.java:110) [geomajas-impl-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.geomajas.internal.service.ConfigurationServiceImpl.getVectorLayer(ConfigurationServiceImpl.java:59) [geomajas-impl-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.geomajas.command.feature.SearchByLocationCommand.execute(SearchByLocationCommand.java:134) [geomajas-command-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.geomajas.command.feature.SearchByLocationCommand.execute(SearchByLocationCommand.java:71) [geomajas-command-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.geomajas.command.feature.SearchByLocationCommand$$FastClassByCGLIB$$aa9c342f.invoke() [cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191) [cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.geomajas.command.feature.SearchByLocationCommand$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$21f5379b.execute() [cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.geomajas.internal.service.CommandDispatcherImpl.execute(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:114) [geomajas-impl-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.geomajas.gwt.server.mvc.GeomajasController.execute(GeomajasController.java:117) [geomajas-face-common-gwt-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561) [gwt-servlet-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) [gwt-servlet-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) [gwt-servlet-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-servlet-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.geomajas.gwt.server.mvc.GeomajasController.handleRequest(GeomajasController.java:65) [geomajas-face-common-gwt-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1162) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.geomajas.servlet.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:201) [geomajas-common-servlet-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1153) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:536) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:928) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409) [jetty-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) [jetty-util-6.1.20.jar:6.1.20]

it is a bug or i have to set something in my vector layer(road layer) configuration to remove this error ?

Regards.